# Opening and Closing two instances of Firefox Browser

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to open two different urls side by side.
First if opens url1 does some checks
Then it should open url2 and do some checks
Then it should closee both url1 and url2 after doing the tests

I have been able to open two url1 and url2 but the tearDown is closing only url2.

I want my tearDown to close both urls.

This is the code I have tried

```
class Login(unittest.TestCase):

    site_url1 = "https://www.google.com/"
    site_url2 = "https://www.facebook.com/"

    def setUp(self):
        # create a new Firefox session
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser = self.browser
        browser.get(self.site_url1)

    def more_loggin(self):
        # create a new Firefox session
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser = self.browser
        browser.get(self.site_url2)            

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()
```

Above code is only closing site_url2, I want it to close the other url as well.
Seems like the self.browser has value of site_url2 and hence is not able to close the other one.
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is because you set `self.browser` every time you call `setUp` or `more_loggin`.
this means that if you call one function, let's say `setUp()` and then you call `more_loggin`, you lose the instance of `Firefox` which was created by `setUp`, and `self.browser` gets a new instance, created at the start of `more_loggin`.

when you call `tearDown`, only the last instance which is stored in `self.browser` will close, and all of the others will remain open.

I suggest you save all of the instances in a list, defined at the class-level, and then `tearDown` should iterate over every instance and close it.

```
class Login(unittest.TestCase):

    instances = []

    site_url1 = "https://www.google.com/"
    site_url2 = "https://www.facebook.com/"

    def openFirefox(self):
        # create a new Firefox session        
        firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
        # save session in instances        
        self.instances.append(firefox)
        # return the session    
        return firefox

    def setUp(self):
        browser = self.openFirefox()
        browser.open(self.site_url1)

    def more_loggin(self):
        browser = self.openFirefox()
        browser.open(self.site_url2)

    def tearDown(self):
        for browser in self.instances:
            # close every instance in instances        
            browser.quit()
```